# Strange Issue with Hard Drive accessible from both Windows 11 and Manjaro KDE

Tags: hard-drive, windows-11, manjaro, dualboot

I have a dual boot setup, Windows 11 on one SSD and Manjaro Linux on the other. I also have several data hard drives, all with GPT partition tables and formatted to NTFS and accessible from both OS's.

One of the data drives, however, is behaving strangely. I thought at first that it was on the verge of failure, because I booted up one day and found the drive was only accessible from Linux (and BIOS). It wasn't even visible to disk utility or disk management in Windows. All SMART indicators suggest drive health was fine, but I've read that if Windows can't see the drive and Linux can it's most likely due to some corruption of the partition table, so I assumed the drive would soon fail and backed up all of my data off of it.

Today, however, I made a discovery. Windows *can* see the drive so long as I boot into Windows directly from a totally powered off state. It's only if I boot into Linux, and then reboot back into Windows without totally powering off the computer in between that the drive cannot be found in Windows.

When I say a totally powered off state I mean that I need to flip the switch on the power supply, so that all components cease getting power. I assume that what's happening is that cutting the power to the drive "resets" something and allows Windows to see it again.

I should add that this behavior is highly reproducible; I know exactly what to do to get the drive to not be visible to Windows (reboot into Linux, reboot into Windows), and what to do to get it to be visible again (shutdown, flip switch on power supply, reboot into Windows).

So my question: What is happening, and can I fix it so that the drive is visible from Windows and Linux without fully powering off in between reboots?

Comment: When dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. Do that and check if it changes the bahavior.

Comment: It is already disabled, assuming you mean this setting https://ibb.co/s1cN7N9